# What is the meaning of negative empirical Likelihood in HLDA Mallet?

Tags: nlp, lda, topic-modeling, mallet

I am using mallet to train a hierarchical LDA model. However when calculating the empirical Likelihood using:

```
double empiricalLikelihood = hlda.empiricalLikelihood(1000, testing);
```

I am getting a negative number.
How can I interpret the meaning of that negative number?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

It's the log of a probability. All probabilities are between 0-1, so their log is negative.